# Mongodb: How to change an element of a nested arrary?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

From what I have read it is impossible to update an element in an nested array using the positional operator `$` in `mongo`.  The `$` only works one level deep.  I see it is a requested feature in `mongo 2.7`.

Updating the whole document `one level up` is not an option because of write conflicts.  I need to just be able to change the `'username'` for a particular reward program for instance.

One of the ideas would to be pull, modify, and push the entire `'reward_programs'` element but then I would loose the order.  Order is important.

Consider this document:

```
 {
  "_id:"0,
  "firstname":"Tom",
  "profiles" : [
               {
                    "profile_name": "tom",
                    "reward_programs:[
                                        {
                                            'program_name':'American',
                                            'username':'tomdoe',
                                        },
                                        {
                                            'program_name':'Delta',
                                            'username':'tomdoe',
                                        }
                                      ]
               }
            ]
}
```

How would you go about specifically changing the `'username'` of `'program_name'=Delta`?

Answer (score 1):

After doing more reading it looks like this is unsupported in mongodb at the moment.  Positional updates are only supported for one level deep.  The feature might be added for mongodb 2.7.

The are a couple of work arounds.

1) Flatten out your database structure.  In this case, make 'reward_programs' it's own collection and do your operation on that.

2) Instead of arrays of dicts, use dicts of dicts.  That way you can just have an absolute path down to the object you need to modify.  This can have drawbacks to query flexibility.

3) Seems hacky to me but you can also walk the list on the nested array find it's position index in the array and do something like this:

```
 users.update({'_id': request._id, 'profiles.profile_name': profile_name}, {'$set': {'profiles.$.reward_programs.{}.username'.format(index): new_username}})
```

4) Read in the whole document, modify, write back.  However, this has possible write conflicts

Setting up your database structure initially is extremely important.  It really depends on how you are going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this:

```
doc = collection.find_one({'_id': 0})
doc['profiles'][0]["reward_programs"][1]['username'] = 'new user name'
#replace the whole collection
collection.save(doc)
```